# Will my Windows 10 still be reserved despite a factory reset?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, factory-defaults

Ok, so my computer had a factory reset, and I'm stuck back at Windows 8. I am currently attempting to get back to Windows 8.1. Previously, I had y copy of Windows 10 reserved, and couldn't wait to start developing on the UWP. Once, I get Windows 8.1 again and I sign into my Microsoft account, will my reservation, and the GWX process still be valid? If not, what can I do to get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once, I get Windows 8.1 again and I sign into my Microsoft account,
>   will my reservation, and the GWX process still be valid?

It is important you understand the reservation actually means.

As the [Windows 10 FAQ](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq) states:

> **What happens when I reserve?**
>
> **When you reserve, you can confirm your device is compatible with
>   Windows 10.** Between reservation and when your upgrade is ready, the
>   files you need for the upgrade will be downloaded to your PC to make
>   the final installation go more quickly. Then, when your upgrade is
>   ready after July 29, 2015, you get a notification that lets you get
>   started with your upgrade.

All the reservation is doing is making sure your device is compatible with Windows 10.  You have already confirmed that is the case.

[After July 29th 2015 you will be able to download a Windows 10 .iso from Microsoft](https://superuser.com/questions/945159/is-it-possible-to-get-windows-10-upgrade-as-an-iso-image-to-make-a-bootable-ins)

Microsoft plans to support the build that will come out on July 29th 2015 for 10 years.  Once you upgrade to Windows 10 that machine itself will have a perpetual license to it.  Which means for as long as that device works in the case of an OEM machine, you will be able to install Windows 10 on that device, and you will be able to activate it.

Comment: So, I will have to burn the ISO myself?

Comment: @James_Parsons - No;  Eventually you will just install Windows 10 by indicating you want Windows 10 then downloading it through Windows Update  I suggest you do some more reading on the subject.

Comment: I have. Apparently, on Windows 8.0 and 8.1, the ISO will act as an installer, but in Windows 7, you will have to prepare the ISO first.

Comment: I have not read the same information.

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-do-a-build-to-build-upgrade-using-windows/35160fbe-9352-4e70-9887-f40096ec3085

Comment: That is because Windows 8.x has a built-in feature to mount .ISO files and Windows 7 does not.