# If I cancel my scheduled upgrade, have I missed my chance to get W10 free?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

[image]

I intend to take my free W10 upgrade and have previously said I want to reserve my copy. Now, it has started trying to schedule an install in a few days but I'm not ready yet.

If I cancel the scheduled update, will this cancel my interest in upgrading to W10 for free and all the downloaded files will be removed? Or will it just pause the process until I get ready to upgrade?

My other option is to keep pushing the install date a few days away every time it gets close, but this is bound to go wrong!

Comment: You don't have to reserve Windows 10 to upgrade to Windows 10, you have until April 29th 2016 to perform the upgrade, on April 30th 2016 you will have to purchase a Windows 10 license.  Just cancel the scheduled upgrade and install Windows 10 from an .ISO before July 29th manually yourself

Comment: So I _will_ lose the opportunity to install it through Windows Update if I hit cancel? I can't turn this back on - that's rather important, worthy of an answer. Also - are MS providing free ISOs?

Comment: I never said you would lose the opportunity.  Read my comment again, you can upgrade to Windows 10, even if you don't reserve the upgrade.  That part of the process is NOT REQUIRES AND HAS NEVER been required.  Your question about the .ISO files have already been answered several times now on this website, do some research on that subject, if you still can't find the answer I will answer it again.

Comment: I never said you claimed that. Read _my_ comment again. Being able to upgrade through Windows Update is quite handy and would be my preferred mechanism.

Comment: "So I will lose the opportunity to install it through Windows Update if I hit cancel?" - I answered this question in my first comment.  The upgrade process is identical if you use Windows Update or use the .ISO, a reservation isn't required, to upgrade to a windows 10.  By asking me a question I already answered it seems to me you didn't read my comment.  The reservation is literally just you scheduling to download the update, if you want, you can download manually.

Comment: As I said, this is valuable information and hence I asked you to provide it as an answer

Comment: I already provided the information I shared with you, as an answer, to a different question months ago.  *I don't repeat answers.*  Besides I see no request, for me to post what I provided, as an answer.

Comment: So link your answer then.

Comment: [here](http://superuser.com/questions/945355/will-my-windows-10-still-be-reserved-despite-a-factory-reset/945431#945431) or [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1000240/windows-10-update-1511-failed-and-no-longer-offered/1000252#1000252) and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/946348/can-i-install-the-free-windows-7-8-10-upgrade-on-a-new-empty-drive/946355#946355) are just a few.  I am to lazy to find my other answers that might exist.

Answer (score 4):

If you cancel the scheduled update you will not lose your right to upgrade. You can always upgrade later.

However you are only eligible for free upgrade for **1 year** after the launch date of Windows 10, which is [**July 29, 2015**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10), according to the [latest statement](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/01/21/the-next-generation-of-windows-windows-10/) of Microsoft on this subject.