# w10 live usb from iso

Tags: usb, windows-10, iso-image

I downloaded an ISO of W10 to upgrade my parents laptop as they have limited download limits.

I also downloaded the media creation tool from the microsoft site but it seems to be a glorified download tool.

I have seen [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/945159/is-it-possible-to-get-windows-10-upgrade-as-an-iso-image-to-make-a-bootable-ins) for updating. I'm fine with doing an upgrade and a wipe but how do I create a live boot image onto a usb on a w7 machine?

I would prefer not to use a third party tool to do this. I have access to both an Ubuntu and W7 machine.

Comment: I always use Rufus: http://rufus.akeo.ie/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the ISO, you can use [this tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) to create your bootable USB drive.

Comment: Thanks. Terribly named tool, but seems to be exactly what I am looking for